# Send List of QCoordinates from C++ to QML

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qml

I would like to send list of QGeoCoordinate which look like this: `QList<QGeoCoordinate> coordinates;` to QMLMapPolyline: in way that i will be able to assign it to path

```
   MapPolyline {
         line.width: 3
         line.color: 'green'
         path: appcontrol.coordinates
                path: [
                     { latitude: 49.983, longitude: 20.9332 },
                     { latitude: 50.983, longitude: 21.9332 }
                      ]
     }
```

i have tryied a multiple ways and i can't find solution on Qt documentation web.
 Does anyone did it before or maybe can tell me where to search ?.
 Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Please show more of the C++ code you've tried and what compile or runtime errors you ran into.

Comment: ahh sorry i did't find this post. It solve my problem. Thank you very much